# WebSocket has different definitions in different modules error on xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have not had a Mac in a while but I am now trying to update my iOS app. But I seem to be hitting this error.
Code:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC14SwiftWebSocket9WebSocket")
@interface WebSocket : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger hash;
/// Create a WebSocket object with a deferred connection; the connection is not opened until the .open() method is called.
- (nonnull instancetype)init;
@end`
```

Error:

```
'WebSocket' has different definitions in different modules; first difference is definition in module 'SwiftWebSocket.Swift' found 0 referenced protocols
```

Any advice?